# Can I listen to just the audio of a movie on an iPhone?

Tags: audio, video, iphone

I downloaded a movie (live concert) to my iphone 4g and would like to listen to it thru my car stereo via the 3.5mm mini jack to aux port?  just want to hear the audio stream, not see the video stream

Comment: Plug it in as you would head phones, play movie, and then turn off the display.

Comment: Sorry, but what is exactly iphone **4g**. Is it **ipod** 4g? or iphone **4s**.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can do it with headphones, you can output it to an AUX.